# Importing Bootstrap/Bootstrap-Vue into Scoped CSS

Tags: css, vue.js, google-chrome-extension, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I am developing a chrome extension and am using Bootstrap-Vue on my Vue files. Currently, I imported bootstrap/bootstrap-vue into my js file, but this causes the styling to take place on a global level. Ideally, I would like a way for the bootstrap to only be scoped onto my inserted files. Is there a way to do this in the  section of the Vue file?

// In .js file

```js
import VModal from 'vue-js-modal'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue';
```

// I tried this in the Vue file but no effect was shown

```html
<style scoped src="bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"></style>
<style scoped src="bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css"></style>
```

Answer (score -1):

To import the style only within a component use this inside the `<style>` tag

```js
  @import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
  @import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css';
```

Comment: If you do that, the style with leak outside the component.

Answer (score -2):

José's answer was nearly correct :

```html
<style scoped>
@import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
@import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css';
</style>
```